# Extending Kalman filters with discrete (catergorical) state variable?

Tags: kalman-filter

I'm new to Kalman filters.

I have a use case similar to the [one-dimensional train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application,_technical) example.
But I have railroad track with switches and mergers. So it's a non-trivial topology.

I would like to model the system as a graph with N nodes and E directed edges. Each edge has length (weight) L. So the system state `(e, x, v)` consists of the current edge `e`, the distance `x` along the edge and velocity `v`.

**The edge `e` is a discrete (categorical) variable, which does not fit the standard Kalman Gaussian methods. Can the Kalman filter be extended to this?**

- Measurements: I do have measurements of `(e, x)` and related position error `err_x`. There is no error related to the measured edge `e`.
- Prediction model: We can assume a constant speed model with zero-mean acceleration as in the Wikipedia example.
  In case of a prediction through a node with multiple outgoing edges (rail switch) I'm not sure if I should return a multi-modal distribution.
  I don't have a requirement that this should run in real-time, so it is possible to look ahead in the data and see which edge is taken. Or to use some kind of backwards smoothing is also ok.

The graph is in priciple cyclic, but in practice length of the edges are way larger than the measurement errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard Kalman filter definitely would not be able to handle this. If you were running this sequentially, I would suggest searching the literature for "Multiple Model" Kalman filters. Basically what will happen is, when a rail switch is reached with $x$ possible paths forward, you will create $x$ Kalman filters, starting with the same point. Then you devise some kind of test statistic to determine which of the $x$ Kalman filters matches the data best.

Running it as a batch is an interesting constraint. Your problem is similar to Multiple Hypothesis Tracking (see e.g. "Multiple hypothesis tracking for multiple target tracking" by Blackman). You might be able to get away with enumerating all of the possible hypotheses, depending on how many edges and nodes you have. Then you can evaluate all of those hypotheses to determine which hypothesis is most consistent with your data.

Comment: Great, I found this article. https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pstone/Courses/393Rfall11/resources/RC09-Quinlan.pdf